# Vega interaction dashboard

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I’m new on Vega.
I would like to build a dashboard similar to this one https://swiss-avalanches.github.io/explore/, made with D3, with Vega or Vega-lite. Do you know if it is possible?
Do you have an example with a similar level of complexity of interactions and dynamics with Vega or Vega-lite?
I can’t find an example in that gallery.

Comment: have you checked the examples?  Take a look at https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_layered_crossfilter.html.

Comment: Your best approach is to first start with Vega-Lite which packages common visualizations and interactions.  I think your examples are covered by https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for project with more interactions, and charts that change depending on the others.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/) to manage my data. Kibana is an interface that sits on top of Elastic and is a great way to create interactive dashboards i.e. filtering and manipulating data. Fortunately they have support for Vega and Vega-Lite visualisations so you can also utilise the benefits of these great tools.

One thing to note, is that tiles in Kibana are separate, so if you are looking for a non-filtering mechanism between visualisations this could be tricky.

Good luck.